# Nuget Sitefinity Repository down?

Tags: nuget, connection, nuget-server

Is http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget working for you guys as a Nuget package source? We are getting the following error:

[image]

This has been happening since January 19th 3 PM GMT.

Answer (score 1):

I made a phone call to telerik to tell them, "your nuget server is down". As you can see, **it's up again** :-)

Sidenode:

-> If you have the packages local and a nuget feed will get down for some hours... Just don't include those feeds, then it will install the local packages (if available) without conntact any server.

Comment: Thanks... :) well it was erroring out in our devops pipeline. It is working now.